# Cannot pip install pyflux

Tags: python, python-3.x

while I pip-installed the pyflux, it shows the error message as follows, any help is requested to solve the problem:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u3pqer2_\\pyflux_ee8202a3600d45dda467e25273ec5c02\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u3pqer2_\\pyflux_ee8202a3600d45dda467e25273ec5c02\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9fr9bs8o\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Include\pyflux' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm not sure is there any reason related to the environment I build for python, because not only pyflux, but the pygrapghviz cannot be loaded as well.

While I search pyflux file, it existed but cannot be loaded under conda.[image]

Comment: "Check the logs for full command output."

Answer (score 0):

Often times when I have a problem with pip, it's because it's conflicting with something in my environment. Try creating a new environment and testing it out to see if it works there. Also, when using conda, it is recommended to use pip only when necessary. Looks like there is a conda package for pyflux.

```
conda install -c mzh pyflux
```